# Issue with Editor for Mediawiki 1.23

Tags: mediawiki-extensions

Recently I installed MediaWiki 1.23 version on Oracle enterprise linux 6 and it's working fine. The issue is with the WYSIWYG_1.23/CKeditor editors. I tried configuring both the editors but neither of them worked. I added the below mentioned code to LocalSettings.php file:

require_once( "$IP/extensions/WYSIWYG-CKeditor-CKeditor_v4/WikiEditor/WikiEditor.php" );

require_once("$IP/extensions/WYSIWYG-CKeditor-CKeditor_v4/WYSIWYG/WYSIWYG.php");

$wgGroupPermissions['registered_users']['wysiwyg']=true;

$wgGroupPermissions['*']['wysiwyg'] = true;
$wgDefaultUserOptions['cke_show'] = 'richeditor';

$wgDefaultUserOptions['riched_use_toggle'] = true;

$wgDefaultUserOptions['riched_start_disabled'] = false;

$wgDefaultUserOptions['riched_toggle_remember_state'] = true;

$wgDefaultUserOptions['riched_use_popup'] = false;

$wgFCKEditorExcludedNamespaces[] = NS_MEDIAWIKI;

$wgFCKEditorExcludedNamespaces[] = NS_TEMPLATE;

$wgDefaultUserOptions['usebetatoolbar'] = 1;

$wgDefaultUserOptions['usebetatoolbar-cgd'] = 1;

$wgDefaultUserOptions['wikieditor-preview'] = 0;

$wgDefaultUserOptions['wikieditor-publish'] = 0;

as suggested in some of the forums but it did not work. Can anyone help me in resolving this issue? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing this line is incorrect and unneeded, please remove it:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['registered_users']['wysiwyg']=true;
```